# How does Mixed In Key determine the key of a track?

Tags: audio

Mixed in Key is a piece of software that analyzes mp3s and determines the key of the song, e.g. it will run and tell you if the song is, roughly, in F-minor or A-major.

The purpose is to aid in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mixing

Is there a standard algorithm for inferring the key from a PCM waveform?

Warning: music theory and signals processing noob here:

Is it as simple as taking the DFT and attempting to map the most common frequencies to notes, and treating the most dominant notes as the key?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not quite that simple, but your suggested path may well be part of it.

Rather than looking at just the most common notes, you likely need to assess many notes to deduce the key signature and then assess the most common chords to distinguish between major and minor keys, or conceivably all the modal keys used in gregorian chant and some jazz.

Mixed in Key claims to have a patented algorithm, so a patent search might turn up some info.

Google found a [conference journal citation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1385971) that looks potentially interesting, but to get the article you have to pay something to IEEE, and I'm not quite intrigued enough to spend money on it.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the abstract of Mixed in Key's patent is that they determine the predominant pitches and the sequence in which they occur, and compare that with a database of other recordings, but I didn't read past the abstract:

http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20080314231

I have heard informal research of pop music indicating that the most common chord is not usually the "root", or key, but rather the "dominant". Dominant is a music theory term for the second most important note/chord in a key: one fifth above the root. So if you hear mostly E's, the song might be in E, but slightly more likely A. This doesn't tell you major or minor, and it's hardly enough to be sure, so Mixed in Key's technique that looks at sequences is clearly superior.